# AWS S3 upload file synchronously

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, meteor, async-await

I am using Meteor on Server side where I used Method Calls to return data.

So there I am trying to upload file to AWS S3 Bucket synchronously.

Here is a sample code:

```
Meteor.methods({

    uploadImage: function (params) {

        var AWS = Npm.require('aws-sdk');

        AWS.config.loadFromPath(process.env["PWD"]+'/private/awss3/s3_config.json');
        var s3Bucket = new AWS.S3( { params: {Bucket: 'users-profile-pictures'} } );

        buf = Buffer.from(params.baseimage.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),'base64')
        var data = {
          Key: params.fileName, 
          Body: buf,
          ContentEncoding: 'base64',
          ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
        };

        s3Bucket.putObject(data, function(err, data){
            if (err) { 
              console.log(err);
              console.log('Error uploading data: ', data); 
            } else {
              console.dir(data);
              console.log('successfully uploaded the image!');
            }
        });

        return data;
    },
});
```

Now here I want to return the response I got from AWS SDK Callback. How can I make this upload synchronously?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to synchronously upload files to S3 using aws-sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57420576/how-to-synchronously-upload-files-to-s3-using-aws-sdk)

Comment: @AnonCoward I already used await but it gives syntax error unexpected token

Answer (score 1):

I'm not expert with AWS SDK, but for my experience, all internet requests are asyncronous, because server take time to respond. Anyway, you need to use it as you are currently using, or you need to do all your script asyncronous and then add the await tag to await the function output: `await s3Bucket.putObject(...`.

Comment: I already used await but it gives syntax error unexpected token

Answer (score 1):

In Meteor you use `wrapAsync` to make async calls sync:

```js
const putObjectSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(s3Bucket.putObject);

Meteor.methods({
  uploadImage: function (params) {
  
    var AWS = Npm.require('aws-sdk');
    
    AWS.config.loadFromPath(process.env["PWD"]+'/private/awss3/s3_config.json');
    var s3Bucket = new AWS.S3( { params: {Bucket: 'users-profile-pictures'} } );
    
    buf = Buffer.from(params.baseimage.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),'base64')
    var data = {
      Key: params.fileName, 
      Body: buf,
      ContentEncoding: 'base64',
      ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
    };
    
    const result = putObjectSync(data); 
    // Note that errors will throw an exception, which is what you want, as
    // they are handled by Meteor, letting the method called know that something
    // went wrong.

    return result;
  },
});
```

Comment: Not working it gives error: this.makeRequest is not a function

Comment: `this.makeRequest` doesn't appear in this code. Are you sure it is not thrown somewhere else?

Comment: @Christain I havnet used this.makeRequest in my code atleast